# How to Force all DATE columns to LocalDateTime in jOOQ generator?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to force all Oracle DATE columns to LocalDateTime.

What I tried:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <name>LOCALDATETIME</name>
    <userType>java.time.LocalDateTime</userType>
    <types>DATE\(*\)</types>
</forcedType>
```

But jOOQ still generates LocalDate.

How must the forcedType look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<types>` expression reads "DATE followed by any number of `(` followed by exactly one `)`. You probably wanted this:

```xml
<types>DATE(\(.*\))?</types>
```

As a side note: You don't really need to specify the `<userType>` to profit from the ["data type rewriting"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/) feature. Specifying a name that matches a type from `SQLDataType` is enough.

#### Bug

Notice there was a bug in jOOQ 3.11 by which `<name>LOCALDATETIME</name>` did not work: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8493

This is fixed in jOOQ 3.12. For the time being, use `<name>TIMESTAMP</name>` instead, along with `<javaTimeTypes>`

Comment: Thanks. And how would I have to write the expression if the column in the DB is only DATE? Because the generator still generates LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime

Comment: Is this maybe related to this bug https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6497

Comment: It finally worked with  <forcedType>
                                            <name>timestamp</name>
                                            <types>DATE(\(.*\))?</types>
                                        </forcedType>

Comment: Hmm interesting. Indeed, I missed that detail. You have to specify `TIMESTAMP`, because the other data type doesn't really exist. Of course, that's not correct according to the manual. It should be safe to expect this to work, given that there is a `SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME`. Perhaps it's related to that other bug #6497, but I think this one can be fixed in isolation. I've created https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8493 for this. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: It's a pleasure to help make jOOQ even better

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Sounds like there's no way back for you :-)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: This is now implemented in jOOQ 3.12

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out